# How to show user location accurately in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, leaflet, maps, geoip

I have a problem about showing user's location with latitude and longitude on map. After I host/deploy my project I noticed the location is wrong. It shows some place I don't even know probably my internet provider's location.

What I use in my Laravel project:

- Leaflet.js
- geoip

My Controller I want to show the map in my `create.blade` file:

```
//user's location 
private function getLocation(){
     //return location coordinate from user's ip
     return geoip()->getLocation($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
}

//create
public function create($id, Request $request){
   $location = $this->getLocation();
return view('presence.create', compact(
            'location'
        ));
    }
```

I sceptical about `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` line, I'm not sure it shows true user's ip or it is my provider's ip

`leaflet.js` in my blade file:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([-6.297979, 106.922899], 10);

    L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    //put user's latitude and longitude to marker 
    L.marker([ {{ $location->lat }}, {{ $location->lon }}]).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup('{{ auth()->user()->name }}')
        .openPopup();

    //destination marker
    var destination = L.marker([ -6.297979, 106.922899]).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup('Tujuan')
        .openPopup();
    destination._icon.classList.add("huechange");
    
    var circle = L.circle([-6.297979, 106.922899], {
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        radius: 20
    }).addTo(map);

</script>
```

Comment: After all, geolocation is done on the [client side](https://leafletjs.com/examples/mobile/), not on the server side.